# Xcode tables refresh on button click

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

I have a table which is populated with JSON. It works as a calendar. When the date is clicked, the table below should be populated with the events for that day.

These populate the tables after the data has been found but only does it once.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return(GlobalVar.TodaysEvents.count)

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventCell", for: indexPath) as! WhitelistTableViewCell

    cell.startTime.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

    print(GlobalVar.TodaysEventsTimes[indexPath.row])

    cell.startTime.text = (GlobalVar.TodaysEventsTimes[indexPath.row] as! String)
    cell.Summary.text = GlobalVar.TodaysEvents[indexPath.row] as? String

    return(cell)
}
```

I have seen other posts like this and they use:

```
self.tableView.reload()
```

However, when i try this, it doesn't recognise "tableView" and simply doesn't work.

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your VC, such as where your are trying to call reload and what error you are getting

Comment: How are you reloading your tableView? You need to swap the data (inside the cellForRow) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a reference to your tableView ( New Referencing Outlet ) and then do this :

```
yourTableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I should've known that.

Comment: happy to help @HarryB

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you are reload the tableview but i think you reload the table view at different thread. That's why please reload the table view after inserting the data in array.